# How to start The Secret Of Monkey Island in ScummVM?

Tags: scummvm, the-secret-of-monkey-island

When I'm trying to add The Secret Of Monkey Island on ScummVM v2.5.0 on my Chromebook I get the error "ScummVM could not find any game in the specified directory!". Does someone knows how to solve this?

[image: Popup with "ScummVM could not find any game in the specified directory"]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Arqade!!! I have a segustion, maybe explain your question more by typing it instead of just showing pictures. Because I know that I cannot access the pictures, this would be a great help at helping us solve your problem!! Maybe tell us the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game has to be somewhere installed. In my case, I installed it with Wine. Go to edit game and the tab path here, you have to navigate to the game folder.

[image: scummvm]

Then it should be added.

[image: monkey island]